# Sort Table by click in header tag regardless of it is numeric, alphabetical or date

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort my table by [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)(only [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)pure, not library and not framework, only [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)pure).

Each column sort by clicking in every header tag and currently the sort is alphabetical but I need the sort will be numeric or alphabetical or date regardless of it. The data is a Json that come from the other side and could have numeric or alphabetical or date column.

This is my sort code:

```
function sortMainTable(_num) {
  var table, rows, sw, i, x, y;
  table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
  sw = true;
  while (sw) {
    sw = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[_num];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[_num];
      if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        sw = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example [json](/questions/tagged/json):

```
places = [{
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "country": "USA",
    "price:": "130.90",
    "date": "02/12/2015"
  },
  {
    "city": "Boston",
    "country": "USA",
    "price:": "11.40",
    "date": "10/04/2014",
  },
  {
    "city": "Chicago",
    "country": "USA",
    "price:": "320.40"
    "date": "06/05/2017",
  },
]
```

As I told above, I need the sort will be numeric or alphabetical or date regardless of it. (if the column is numeric, the table sort is order by numeric column, and if the column is alphabetical, the table sort is order by alphabetical column, if the column is date, the table sort is order by date column)

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you update your question with the `JSON` data?

Comment: look the edit question please

Answer (score 0):

What you want is most likely a [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). Where you can sort on alphanumerics, "naturally". There are a myriad of options out there on `npm` that you can use as reference. The first hit on google is [javascript-natural-sort](https://github.com/Bill4Time/javascript-natural-sort). This should point you in the right direction.

Once you have that, I would bind an event handler to your table header, which passes along the column name you wish to `.sort()` on, then natural sort your `places` array based on that key, then rerender the table.

Answer (score 0):

In **JavaScript** you can sort arrays of objects by using native [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
>   the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order
>   is according to string Unicode code points.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **compareFunction *Optional*** Specifies a function that defines
>   the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each
>   character's Unicode code point value, according to the string
>   conversion of each element.
>
> **Return value**
>
> The sorted array. Note that the array is sorted in place,
>   and no copy is made.

In your **`places`** variable, you have to compare:

- **Strings:** By using **`>`** or **`<`** sign, in the compare function.
- **Numbers:** By using **`-`** sign, in the compare function.
- **Dates:** You can convert string date (`02/12/2015`) to the timestamp equivalent (`1423717200000`) by using: `new Date("02/12/2015").getTime()`. So you can use **`-`** sign, in the compare function.

I've rewrite your code to:

1. Render the table with the **`places`** variable data, dynamically without ordering.
2. Render the data when it is sorted or not.
3. Set the ordering control in the headers.
4. Write a helper function to sort arrays according `key`, `data` and `type` parameters. Returns the sorted data.

```js
(function() {
  var places = [{
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "country": "USA",
    "price": "130.90",
    "date": "02/12/2015"
  }, {
    "city": "Boston",
    "country": "USA",
    "price": "11.40",
    "date": "10/04/2014",
  }, {
    "city": "Chicago",
    "country": "USA",
    "price": "320.40",
    "date": "06/05/2017",
  }];

  // 4.
  function sortByKey(key, data, type) {
    if (key === "price") {
      if (type === "asc") { // ↑
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return (a[key] * 1) > (b[key]);
        });
      } else { // ↓
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return (a[key] * 1) < (b[key]);
        });
      }
    } else if (key === "date") {
      if (type === "asc") {
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return new Date(a[key]).getTime() - new Date(b[key]).getTime();
        });
      } else {
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return new Date(b[key]).getTime() - new Date(a[key]).getTime();
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (type === "asc") {
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a[key] > b[key];
        });
      } else {
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a[key] < b[key];
        });
      }
    }
    return data;
  }

  // 3.
  function setSorterControl(data) {
    // Remove the span class after sorting.
    function reset() {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#mainTable th span"), i, len = elems.length, obj;
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        obj = elems[i];
        obj.removeAttribute("class");
      }
    }
    
    /*
      Render the sorted data in the tbData element.
      Set the data-type attribute with the proper value after click in the header control.
      Set the proper span class when its clicked to sort the data.
     */
    function sorter(e) {
      var tbData = document.getElementById("tbData"), elem = e.target;
      tbData.innerHTML = sortTable(sortByKey(elem.getAttribute("data-key"), data, elem.getAttribute("data-type")));
      elem.setAttribute("data-type", elem.getAttribute("data-type") === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc");
      reset();
      elem.children[0].className = elem.getAttribute("data-type") === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";

    }
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#mainTable th"), i, len = elems.length, obj;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      obj = elems[i];
      obj.onclick = sorter;
    }
  }
  
  // 1.
  function renderTable(data, type) {
    var html = "", i, header = Object.keys(data[0]), lenHeader = header.length;
    html += "<thead><tr>";
    for (i = 0; i < lenHeader; i++) {
      html += "<th data-key=\"";
      html += header[i];
      html += "\" data-type=\"asc\">";
      html += header[i];
      html += "<span></span></th>";
    }
    html += "</tr></thead><tbody id=\"tbData\">";
    html += sortTable(data);
    html += "</tbody>";
    return html;
  }

  // 2.
  function sortTable(data) {
    var html = "",
      i, j, len = data.length,
      header = Object.keys(data[0]),
      lenHeader = header.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      html += "<tr>";
      for (j = 0; j < lenHeader; j++) {
        html += "<td>";
        html += data[i][header[j]];
        html += "</td>";
      }
      html += "</tr>";
    }
    return html;
  }
  document.getElementById("mainTable").innerHTML = renderTable(places);
  setSorterControl(places);
})();
```

```css
#mainTable {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#mainTable th,
#mainTable td {
  padding: 5px;
}

#mainTable th {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#bcbebf, #eff3f7);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mainTable th span {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#mainTable th span:before {
  content: "↕";
}

#mainTable th span.asc:before {
  content: "↑";
}

#mainTable th span.desc:before {
  content: "↓";
}
```

```html
<table id="mainTable" border="1"></table>
```

[image]