# JS sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm currently attempting to sort an object although I've been facing a `data.sort is not a function` error.

I have taken inspiration from the following StackOverflow answer: [Sort Table by click in header tag regardless of it is numeric, alphabetical or date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923526/sort-table-by-click-in-header-tag-regardless-of-it-is-numeric-alphabetical-or-d).

I have also had a browse of other questions and haven't yet managed to fix my issue, as it tends to lead to other issues such as the value being `undefined`.

Here is my object:

```
{
    "2010-01": {
        "item1": 324,
        "item2": 1075,
        "item3": 940,
        "item4": 441,
        "item5": 1040,
        "item6": 898,
        "item7": 1343
    },
    "2011-02": {
        "item1": 295,
        "item2": 958,
        "item3": 904,
        "item4": 434,
        "item5": 1038,
        "item6": 793,
        "item7": 1246
    },
    "2012-03": {
        "item1": 314,
        "item2": 1062,
        "item3": 980,
        "item4": 494,
        "item5": 1158,
        "item6": 914,
        "item7": 1461
    },
    "2008-04": {
        "item1": 336,
        "item2": 1022,
        "item3": 987,
        "item4": 488,
        "item5": 1014,
        "item6": 792,
        "item7": 1382
    },
    "2007-05": {
        "item1": 332,
        "item2": 1073,
        "item3": 1002,
        "item4": 512,
        "item5": 1104,
        "item6": 840,
        "item7": 1368
    },
    "2005-06": {
        "item1": 311,
        "item2": 981,
        "item3": 837,
        "item4": 432,
        "item5": 1002,
        "item6": 801,
        "item7": 1265
    },
    "2014-07": {
        "item1": 321,
        "item2": 1049,
        "item3": 921,
        "item4": 489,
        "item5": 963,
        "item6": 881,
        "item7": 1340
    },
    "2015-08": {
        "item1": 294,
        "item2": 1071,
        "item3": 960,
        "item4": 506,
        "item5": 910,
        "item6": 885,
        "item7": 1312
    },
    "2016-09": {
        "item1": 281,
        "item2": 1020,
        "item3": 952,
        "item4": 502,
        "item5": 1068,
        "item6": 914,
        "item7": 1397
    },
    "2009-10": {
        "item1": 319,
        "item2": 1058,
        "item3": 985,
        "item4": 546,
        "item5": 1184,
        "item6": 1031,
        "item7": 1448
    },
    "2005-11": {
        "item1": 300,
        "item2": 1021,
        "item3": 967,
        "item4": 474,
        "item5": 1176,
        "item6": 1009,
        "item7": 1387
    },
    "2017-12": {
        "item1": 307,
        "item2": 1027,
        "item3": 924,
        "item4": 427,
        "item5": 1024,
        "item6": 844,
        "item7": 1300
    }
}
```

My function for sorting, which at the minute I've only started by trying order the first item in either ascending or descending order.

```
function sortData(key, data, type) {
        if (key === "item1") {
          if (type === "asc") {
            data.sort(function(a, b) {
              return a[key] > b[key];
            });
          } else {
            data.sort(function(a, b) {
              return a[key] < b[key];
            });
          }
        }
        return data;
      }
```

The `data` is the object, and I've tried to pass it like such: `sortData('item1', [data], 'asc');` as opposed to just `data` but with no luck. If someone could shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the data is not an array and sort is an array method. You can use `Object.keys` to get an array of the keys, sort that and then populate with the values with a `forEach`:

```js
let unsorted_data = { "2010-01": { "item1": 324, "item2": 1075, "item3": 940, "item4": 441, "item5": 1040, "item6": 898, "item7": 1343 }, "2011-02": { "item1": 295, "item2": 958, "item3": 904, "item4": 434, "item5": 1038, "item6": 793, "item7": 1246 }, "2012-03": { "item1": 314, "item2": 1062, "item3": 980, "item4": 494, "item5": 1158, "item6": 914, "item7": 1461 }, "2008-04": { "item1": 336, "item2": 1022, "item3": 987, "item4": 488, "item5": 1014, "item6": 792, "item7": 1382 }, "2007-05": { "item1": 332, "item2": 1073, "item3": 1002, "item4": 512, "item5": 1104, "item6": 840, "item7": 1368 }, "2005-06": { "item1": 311, "item2": 981, "item3": 837, "item4": 432, "item5": 1002, "item6": 801, "item7": 1265 }, "2014-07": { "item1": 321, "item2": 1049, "item3": 921, "item4": 489, "item5": 963, "item6": 881, "item7": 1340 }, "2015-08": { "item1": 294, "item2": 1071, "item3": 960, "item4": 506, "item5": 910, "item6": 885, "item7": 1312 }, "2016-09": { "item1": 281, "item2": 1020, "item3": 952, "item4": 502, "item5": 1068, "item6": 914, "item7": 1397 }, "2009-10": { "item1": 319, "item2": 1058, "item3": 985, "item4": 546, "item5": 1184, "item6": 1031, "item7": 1448 }, "2005-11": { "item1": 300, "item2": 1021, "item3": 967, "item4": 474, "item5": 1176, "item6": 1009, "item7": 1387 }, "2017-12": { "item1": 307, "item2": 1027, "item3": 924, "item4": 427, "item5": 1024, "item6": 844, "item7": 1300 } };

function sortData(key, data, type) {
  let ordered = {};
  let compareFunction = function(a, b) {
    return data[b][key] - data[a][key];
  };
  if (type === "asc") {
    compareFunction = function(a, b) {
      return data[a][key] - data[b][key];
    }
  }
  Object.keys(data).sort(compareFunction).forEach(function(key) {
    ordered[key] = data[key];
  });
  return ordered;
}


console.log(sortData("item1", unsorted_data, 'asc'));
```

And you can still pass your custom compare functions for asc and desc. order to `sort`, but I have omitted that for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm having trouble now with writing my sort methods for ascending and descending. Would you possibly be able to add this to your answer? I know you omitted it but not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Do you want to sort by the date or by the item1 for example?

Comment: I know it's cheeky but if you wouldn't mind doing date and item1 that would be amazing. I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: Ok i edited it so now it sorts by whatever key you pass to the function.

Comment: Hello, this is working fine for only the value is numeric, is there any way that we can sort if the value is string? for eg.  let unsorted_data = { "2010-01": { "item1": "[V11]Encore Sandstone V11" ...... please help.

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses Arrow functions and `reduce` function.

It's a little shorter.

```js
let data = { "2010-01": { "item1": 324, "item2": 1075, "item3": 940, "item4": 441, "item5": 1040, "item6": 898, "item7": 1343 }, "2011-02": { "item1": 295, "item2": 958, "item3": 904, "item4": 434, "item5": 1038, "item6": 793, "item7": 1246 }, "2012-03": { "item1": 314, "item2": 1062, "item3": 980, "item4": 494, "item5": 1158, "item6": 914, "item7": 1461 }, "2008-04": { "item1": 336, "item2": 1022, "item3": 987, "item4": 488, "item5": 1014, "item6": 792, "item7": 1382 }, "2007-05": { "item1": 332, "item2": 1073, "item3": 1002, "item4": 512, "item5": 1104, "item6": 840, "item7": 1368 }, "2005-06": { "item1": 311, "item2": 981, "item3": 837, "item4": 432, "item5": 1002, "item6": 801, "item7": 1265 }, "2014-07": { "item1": 321, "item2": 1049, "item3": 921, "item4": 489, "item5": 963, "item6": 881, "item7": 1340 }, "2015-08": { "item1": 294, "item2": 1071, "item3": 960, "item4": 506, "item5": 910, "item6": 885, "item7": 1312 }, "2016-09": { "item1": 281, "item2": 1020, "item3": 952, "item4": 502, "item5": 1068, "item6": 914, "item7": 1397 }, "2009-10": { "item1": 319, "item2": 1058, "item3": 985, "item4": 546, "item5": 1184, "item6": 1031, "item7": 1448 }, "2005-11": { "item1": 300, "item2": 1021, "item3": 967, "item4": 474, "item5": 1176, "item6": 1009, "item7": 1387 }, "2017-12": { "item1": 307, "item2": 1027, "item3": 924, "item4": 427, "item5": 1024, "item6": 844, "item7": 1300 } };
// ----------------
let byThis = 'item1';
let compare = (k, kk) => data[k][byThis] - data[kk][byThis];

let sorted = Object.keys(data).sort(compare).reduce((a, d) => ({ ...a, ...{ [d]: data[d] } }), {});

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I made the mistake of storing two combined arrays in a string and then trying to use the sort method. Try this:

```
if (charSelected == "all") 
    {
        charArray = heroes.concat(villains).sort();

    }
```